# Remove kivy text input boarders

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to remove the boarder line around a text input or make it invisible?

Sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TextInput` uses as a default theme following images:

- [textinput.png](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/textinput.png) for `background_normal` property
- [textinput_active.png](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/textinput_active.png) for `background_active` property

As you can see, both images contain borders. To remove them, create a white colored image (can be 1x1 pixel) and use it as a background:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:  
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.5, 0.8, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    TextInput
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        pos_hint: { 'center_x' : 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.5 }
        background_normal: 'white.png'
        background_active: 'white.png'
""")

class MyWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ClientApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

You can also consider [creating your own atlas](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html) .

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want borders try this:

```
TextInput:  
    background_color: 0,0,0,0  
    foreground_color: 0,1,255,0.7
```

This will set `TextInput` to black and no white color inside the `TextInput`.